# Why do the boxes get out of place?

Tags: css

I have two websites. In the first, the layout of the "teachers" is fine, see: http://gagapeople.com/hebrew/category/team/teachers/

But since a recent upgrade, the second one doesn't seem to look o.k.: http://gagapeople.com/english/category/team/teachers/

Any idea what piece of css code is breaking this?

Comment: The wordpress system behind it

Comment: are they supposed to look the exact same?

Comment: [You have invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgagapeople.com%2Fhebrew%2Fcategory%2Fteam%2Fteachers%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), where you've placed `<style>` tags inside the `<body></body>`.  Valid placement is only inside the `<head></head>`, and even if it makes no difference to this problem, it could impact cross-browser issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Hebrew version, all of your `.column` elements are the same height.  In English, they have varying heights.  Because you're only using `float:left` (for English) and `float:right` (for Hebrew), you'll have issues with varying heights.

Maybe just add an `.odd` class to the odd `.column` divs and `.even` to the even ones.  Then say:

```
.odd{
  float:left;
}
.even{
  float:right;
}
```